# Return value from callback function using key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem setting a variable from my object which contains JSON.  Here is what the returned JSON looks like

```
{
  "id": "6",
  "FName": "Chris",
  "LName": "Baker",
  "Height": "6'2",
  "Meds": [
    {
      "MedicationName": "acetaminophen",
      "Doseage": "Take 2 daily with food",
      "NumRefills": 2,
      "RefillExp": "2017-05-31T15:38:50.02Z",
      "FirstPrescribed": "2017-05-31T15:38:50.02Z",
      "WFID": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my React code I'm essentially working with different parts of the JSON in different components.  So my App component hands the state down to its respective Component (Overview and Meds).  Overview works fine probably because i hand the entire state down and then based on the key am able to get the root values (i.e. FName, LName).  However i'm struggling with what to do with the Meds.  I'm trying to just hand the meds portion of the JSON from the state down so that Medications pane can just display what is handed down to it.

```
  class App extends ReactComponent {
  ....
  render() {
    //what worked before was needing to set state to this.state.PATIENT[0].Meds
    //use  console.log{this.state.PATIENT} to see if things output properly
    return (
      <App>
        <Article>
          <Header>
            <Section>
              <Accordion openMulti={false} active='0'>
                <AccordionPanel heading='Overview'>
                  <Box colorIndex='light-2' full='horizontal' direction='row' flex={false}>
                    <OverviewPane overview={this.state.PATIENT}/>
                  </Box>
                </AccordionPanel>
                <AccordionPanel heading='Medications'>
                  <Box colorIndex='light-2' full='horizontal' direction='row' flex={false}>
                  **<MedicationsPane meds={this.state.PATIENT.map(function (P,)){return P.Meds})}/>**
                </AccordionPanel>
              </Accordion>
            </Section>
          </Header>
        </Article>
      </App>
    );
  }
}


class MedicationsPane extends React.Component {  

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <List>
            {this.props.meds.map(function(Meds) {
            return <ListItem justify='between' separator='horizontal' key={Meds.MedicationName}>{Meds.MedicationName}</ListItem>;
          })}
      </List>
    );
  }
}
```

I think I need to pass in the key like P.id in order to return the Meds but can't seem to pass in the index.  Or I need to use Children.Map?  Really confused at this point and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really get your problem. Your MedicationsPane take an array of Meds (I don't get why you map PATIENT as it is an object and not an array), and you don't know how to properly render it because you don't know what to put in "key" ? Can you edit your code with (simplified) MedicationsPane component and show your exact problem ?

Comment: Nevosis the MedicationsPane seems to work fine when i hard code my JSON.  I think the issue is within my overview pane and handing state to the meds variable.  When i try something simple that worked in the past such as meds={this.state.PATIENT.Meds[0]} I get an undefined error.  I

Comment: Please do a fiddle. If you send PATIENT.Meds[0], you can't map on props because its an object (doesn't having a meds node, that's why its undefined). I think you're having trouble using map

Comment: Thanks Neovis.  I tried the Fiddle suggestion and when i do as you suggested it is having an issue with Map stating Cannot GET /main.js.map and cites a 404 error.

Comment: Link of the fiddle so we can play with it a little ?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what is the best way to provide a link of a fiddle?  I tried to export to a text file but it didn't provide much more then the error i stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Your Meds in json is an array with just one object so to access Meds use it like json.Meds[0]. Pass it like this:

```
<MedicationsPane meds={this.state.PATIENT.Meds[0]}/>
```

Comment: Thanks Fawaz.  I did try this initially but when I do an error is returned stating "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: @kuruption213 do a `console.log(this.state)` and see if the json exists there. Maybe you can also share the response. Seems the PATIENT has a different format than that given above.